# How can I correctly add an argument to a local function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter an array by a given ID in a function, but I don't know how to add the ID to the filter-method

```
function checkIdFilter(mediaObject, subCollectionId){
    //mediaObject is allMedia[index??]
    console.log("FILTERING ON " + subCollectionId);
    return mediaObject.id == subCollectionId//check if mediaObject has certain ID here;
}
function searchMediaByCollection(subCollectionId) {

    let filteredMedia = allMedia.filter(checkIdFilter);
    // let filteredMedia = allMedia.filter(checkIdFilter(this.mo??, subCollectionId));
}
```

As you can see, I don't know how to correctly pass the Id to the checkIdFilter method, as it (I assume) iterates invisibly over the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `filter` function takes only one parameter: the current object, so you have to wrap your function in another function, and use the closure to reach `subCollectionId`.

```
function checkIdFilter(mediaObject, subCollectionId){
    //mediaObject is allMedia[index??]
    console.log("FILTERING ON " + subCollectionId);
    return mediaObject.id == subCollectionId//check if mediaObject has certain ID here;
}
function searchMediaByCollection(subCollectionId) {
    let filteredMedia = allMedia.filter(media => checkIdFilter(media, subCollectionId);
}
```

or

```
function searchMediaByCollection(subCollectionId) {
    let filteredMedia = allMedia.filter(function(media) {
        return checkIdFilter(media, subCollectionId);
    });
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask details if needed ;)

Comment: Thank you, the first approach works perfectly! haven't tried the second one yet.

Comment: @Sven0567 It is actually the same thing, the arrow function is the most recent notation, it is slightly different, but really, it doesn't matter a lot here. If this answer suits you, please mark it as accepted so that it helps other people!